# C++ Pointers with classes

Tags: c++, pointers

My programming professor requested that we:

- declare a pointer and a Grade variable
- store the variable's address in the pointer variable
- Call the corresponding functions to print the output. (Refer to the functions using the pointer notation, e.g, ptr->function())

However, I'm a little confused. The "Grade" variable is a class variable, but how do I declare the pointer? Do I declare the pointer as an int?

So I would have something like:

```
int *ptr;
Grade grade;
ptr = &grade;
```

Comment: Grade* ptr; Grade grade; ptr = &grade; ptr->function();

Comment: Show us the presentation from your professor.  What does the text book say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close.  But, you declared a pointer to an integer.  That's what `int *` means.  What you want is a pointer to `Grade`:

```
Grade* ptr;
```

The rest of what you wrote looks correct so far.

Once you have `ptr = &grade;`, you can then call methods in `grade` by saying `ptr->foo()` in place of `grade.foo()`.  Both will call the method `foo()` on the variable `grade`.

Comment: I had that then I removed it lol. Thank you though. Pointers always mess me up a little. This is because if I declared it int it would only point to memory the sizof(int) and not my class right?

Comment: @WorldDominator `*int` means: Stores the address of an `int` variable.

Comment: With `int*`, you're telling the compiler the pointer points to an `int`.  So, if you tried to dereference it, the compiler would just give you an `int`, not your object.  If the pointer happened to point to your object, the `int` that you get when you dereference the pointer could well be gibberish.  In general, you ought to make sure that the type of pointer you have is compatible with the thing you have the pointer pointing to.

Comment: @JoeZ thanks, I just need some things laid out straight for me :P

Answer (score 0):

You declared a pointer to int.
Declaring a pointer to a type is always:

```cpp
type * ptr;
```

With that in mind:

```
Grade grade;
Grade *ptr;
ptr = &grade;
// use
ptr->function();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pointer to a class `T`, just write `T* foo`, just as you would expect. So all in all:

```
//Declare Pointer and grade Variable:
Grade grade;
Grade* ptr;

//Store variable's address in pointer:
ptr = &grade;

//Call function:
ptr->function();
```

Comment: i think you mean `T* foo;`

Comment: just write class* T, or write T*?